# 'Async' / 'Await' not working as expected in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

im new to C# and i was trying to figure out async and await . for practice i was trying to start method 1 in which method 2 is called twice . method 2 takes a value and increases it by 1 each 200 ms . instead of running method 2 the program ends after the first line of method 1 .

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method1();
    }

    static int Method2(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            x += 1;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("final" + " " + x + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return x;

    }
    static async Task Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 running");
        int result1 = await Task.Run(() => Method2(0));
        int result2 = await Task.Run(() => Method2(result1));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("result " + result2 * 2);
    }
```

what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is happening that is unexpected?

Comment: ive tried it before with threading and tasks and its supposed to take the value 0 , add 1 ten times to it and then repeat it again . and at the end of method one double it so the final result shoud be 40 . instead the program just ends after the firs line of method 1 ( Consol.WriteLine("1 running")).

Comment: First of all you need `async Main` here and `await Method1();` inside it. Use it instead your current non-async `Main`

Comment: Async != multithreading

Comment: You aren’t telling the program to wait for the async tasks to finsih

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `Method()` you aren't waiting on it. It returns a task object that is not acted upon, and then `Main()` dutifully returns, which ends the program.

You can do this in `Main()`:

```
public static void Main() {
    Method1().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Or use `async Main()` instead:

```
public static async Task Main() {
    await Method1();
}
```

Comment: The second example is cleaner. `static async Task Main() { await Method1(); }`